# how can i get invisible columns in telerik grid mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I have a grid, and I hide sone columns with this code:

```
foreach (var attr in grid.Attr)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
       columns.Bound(attr.key)
         .Width(attr.width)
         .Visible(attr.isVisible);
    })
```

How can I access to all invisibles columns ? 
If I use the command "Hidden()", So the solution was this:

```
var grid = $("#ELISAAssay").data("tGrid");
var hidden = $.grep(grid.columns, function(column) { return column.hidden });
hidden = $.map(hidden, function(column) { return column.member });
```

But, it does not work on visible() command.

thanks,
R.M.

Answer (score 0):

one quick way is to add a class to all invisible cols and then access those cols by the class selector like

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Bound("")
     .Width(90)
     .Visible(false)
     .HtmlAttributes(new{class="hiddenCol"});
})
```

then access it like

```
$(function(){
  console.log($(".hiddenCol"));
});
```